# Symfony Dependency Injection: Set a repository as a service using php

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have the set the following respository as a service on my Symfony 3.2 project:

```
person_in_need_repository:
  class: AppBundle\Repository\PersonInNeedRepository
  factory: ["@doctrine","getRepository"]
  arguments: ["AppBundle:PersonInNeed"]
```

How can I change its annotation in php format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by like this:

```
use AppBundle\Repository\PersonInNeedRepository;

$container->register('app.person_in_need_repository',PersonInNeedRepository::class)
    ->setFactory([new Reference("doctrine"),"getRepository"])
    ->addArgument('AppBundle:PersonInNeed');
```

Also ensure that you have replaced the `services.yml` with `services.php` on `config.yml` when using it as a global way to set the services. Also rename properly the `services.yml`.